# Webpage load and AJAX

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, load, loader

**Good evening everyone**,

I am sorry to ask such a question, but my knowledge on the particular subject is not strong, and I tried hard to search both here and on Google, but it appears that I know the wrong keywords, or perhaps I just missed it when I found it.

I would like to achieve an effect that can be shown whenever a webpage like the ones here, is loaded:

[Birra Dell'Eremo](http://www.birradelleremo.it/)

[Juraj Molnàr](http://jurajmolnar.com/)

[Pal Zileri](http://www.palzileri.com/)

As you can see, the webpages and the sub-pages of the website are all loaded "behind" a preloader, in some cases an image, in others an SVG, no matter.

I would like to know, or at least be pointed to, a good tutorial and way to learn such a thing. I am not only interested in the loader tho', because I did find some resources about the preloading process.

What really interests me is how those webpages, among many others, use loaders to "asynchronously" load content into the page, **making it feel native and real-time each time you change a page from the menu**.

Is it all about using the loader both on arrival and "departure" from a webpage?

Is it fast and "feels real time" because the first time you change web page with the menu, the loader image and a few css rules were cached in the browser?

How does it work, where can I look for it? Which are the **keywords**?

Thank you very much for your patience, I do hope I will not get downvoted for asking such a trivial question, but I had to ask, because I could not reach an answer on my own.

**EDIT**
I might not be the clearest person in my explanation, and for that I ask of you to forgive me, but the effect that I am trying to find (the loading effect both on "entrance" and "exit" from pages) should also send you to the new page, and not load content with AJAX in a predefined DIV or any tag. I heard about the usage of the history API, but that is not what I am looking for.

**EDIT II**
So far no answer has been given, and I wasn't able to find any good answer aswell on the internet, possibly for my lack of keyword knowledge, I presume. I will try to do a loader that works both on load and unload of the page; will let you know as soon as I'm done. Thank you again.

Thanks again.

Comment: without `ajax`, you can use `windown.onload`, and for `ajax`, you can use `$(window).on('load')`, hope this help

Comment: I did think about using those functions, but the question is more about how to achieve real time feeling and a native application feel. I do believe that you are right about those usages, tho'!

Comment: what you mean of real time? did you mean not fake effect and making real loading effect?

Comment: Yes, but that "faking" makes it look like it is real-time, even tho' it really isn't.

Comment: Sorry man, but still I didn't get you on `real-time` and what is wrong with my offer?

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you said, it just isn't the answer I am looking for :)

What I mean by real time is: think about when you visit a normal and non-optimized website. Each time you change page, it goes "blank" and white, loading the new webpage content that was requested from the server.

Now, that can be "played" by adding a loader, with window.onload and AJAX, as you said, but it will not feel "real-time" because when you change page, the loader is only on the new page, and not when you are leaving. That is what I'm looking for. Real time change effect.

Comment: For redirecting user to new page, we have 2 option, #1: simple anchor tag, #2 fetching the content using ajax and reload only content area (looks like redirecting to target page) without reloading whole page. for #1 is simple, on page load, use `window.onload` ad done, and for #2, showing the loader before ajax start and hide the loader on ajax finished. is this your answer? :)